# Alerts of default apps sending sms

Tags: permissions, motorola-droid

Default apps like phone/messaging storage has been alerting me of sending a large number of SMS and even if I select allow the alert comes back in a few seconds again

Comment: This is not a question ...

Comment: The alert keeps on appearing every few second asking me to select allow or deny

Comment: That is still not a question. What do you want from us?